# What to do with the graphics tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The graphics tag is too broad. Usually everything related to graphics should be tagged with it, but then there are things that really would stretch this, like [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/rss-photoframe-app-for-android) where the only relationship is that the application should do a kind of slideshow with graphics pulled over RSS.

[The highest upvoted question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/795/226) seems to deal with creation/edition of icons, [while the lowest](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1510/226) voted seems to be more interested in vectorization editors (if anything) and in between a bunch of question about indexers, image editors and miscellaneous. So, what is the tag about apart of everything related to "graphics"?

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the ~40 questions that have [graphics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) and retagged them where appropriate to [images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images), [graphs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) or [data-visualization](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization). I can't see a consistent use of [graphics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics). While the part that was [data-visualization](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization) was the largest I wouldn't see them as synonym.

So, I'd recommend deletion of [graphics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics). If it reappears, maybe blacklist it?

I did not retag closed questions or ones where I'm unsure, but I think we should get rid of that tag.

(Note that in an earlier version of this answer I recommended synonyming graphics to images, which I no longer think is a good idea).

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe, but we need to do some retagging first. A significant minority of [tag:graphics] questions are about representing data visually, for which we use [tag:data-visualisation] which is perhaps not discoverable by everyone.

Comment: @Gilles I just went and retagged most of the graphics questions to their respective larger brothers "images" and "data-visulization". The remaining 8 questions are either closed or I'm uncertain which way they should go. I've also rewritten my answer, have a look?

Comment: Thank you. I've deleted a few closed questions and retagged the remaining ones, so there is no longer a [tag:graphics] tag.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks mainly to [Angelo Fuchs](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1108), there are currently no questions tagged [graphics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics). There are tags [graphs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs), [vector-graphics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-graphics), [graphic-design](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphic-design), and [pixel-graphics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pixel-graphics). We'll need to watch their usage (as well as the usage of [images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images)) and check if the lack of [graphics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) doesn't cause people to misuse other tags.